# optimize design for a table with 50 columns

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, optimization

I have a table with 50 column and one of my friend has told me to split the table in 4 different table to save 12 column in each table. He proposed a design to have Master table and refer the PK of that master table in other four table, and then create NONCLUSTERED INDEX on the new table in all column as the limit is 900 bytes.

The idea was to improve the performance and convert key lookup to seek. I am not sure that it will really improve performance using join rather I think it hamper the performance, Please suggest me what to do here.

**EDIT**

Existing Table `Test`

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  A BIGINT,
  B BIGINT - FK --From some other table in DB
 ,C1 -Varchar(100),C2 -Varchar(50),C3 -Varchar(50),,C4 -Varchar(50),C5 -Varchar(50),C6 -Varchar(50),C7 -Varchar(50),C8 -Varchar(50) ,C9 -Varchar(50),C10 -Varchar(50)
 ,D1 -Varchar(100),D2 -Varchar(50),D3 -Varchar(50),,D4 -Varchar(50),D5 -Varchar(50), ,D6 -Varchar(50), D7 -Varchar(50),D8 -Varchar(50),D9 -Varchar(50),D10 -Varchar(50)
 ,E1 -Varchar(100),E2 -Varchar(50),E3 -Varchar(50),,E4 -Varchar(50),E5 -Varchar(50),,E6 -Varchar(50), E7 -Varchar(50),E8 -Varchar(50) ,E9 -Varchar(50) ,E10 -Varchar(50)
  F1 -Varchar(100),F2 -Varchar(50),F3 -Varchar(50),,F4 -Varchar(50),F5 -Varchar(50), ,F6 -Varchar(50),F7 -Varchar(50),F8 -Varchar(50) ,F9 -Varchar(50),F10 -Varchar(50)
)
```

Now the proposed design is to have four table with column name as

```
CREATE TABLE TestC
(
  PkId BIGINT,
  A BIGINT - FK --From the Master table Test
  ,C1 -Varchar(100),C2 -Varchar(50),C3 -Varchar(50),,C4 -Varchar(50),C5 -Varchar(50),
   C6 -Varchar(50),C7 -Varchar(50),C8 -Varchar(50) ,C9 -Varchar(50),C10 -Varchar(50)
)
```

Similar way other tables are, and the these tables are used in reading data. With big table `Test` here, I think covering index to use with big table `Test`.

**EDIT2**

I have requirement to read the data from these table after there are added and and in some case they will be update with status column set to 0 after some days and these rows will be no longer used and the table will have new fresh entry for the same user.

The target is to optimize the data read operation and also minimize the time in insert and update, which one would be a better choice here? Please help.

Comment: Your Friend Suggestion is also correct, But that is Based on requirement.First you should tell me the requirement. old table structure. Then we can Decide.

Comment: @PydiRaju I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's necessary to refer what kind of data your table is storing. Let's say that from C1-C10 you're keeping one group of data and it may be possible that the data in C1-C10 may be redundant (ie, it's possible that you may have the same row of data from C1-C10 throughout your Master Table). Hence, it's wasteful to have redundant data because you're wasting storage space to store the same repeating row of data.

So, what your friend advising you to do is called **Normalization**. Normalization is a process in which we systematically examine relations for anomalies and, when detected, remove those anomalies by splitting up the relation into two new, related, relations. Normalization can also be thought of as a **trade-off between data redundancy and performance**. Normalizing a relation reduces data redundancy but introduces the need for joins when all of the data is required by an application such as a report query.

Recall, the Relational Model consists of the elements: relations, which are made up of attributes.

A relation is a set of attributes with values for each attribute such that:

- Each attribute (column) value must be a single value only.
- All values    for a given attribute (column ) must be of the same
  data type.
- Each    attribute (column) name must be unique.
- The order of attributes    (columns) is insignificant
- **No two tuples (rows) in a    relation can be    identical.**
- The order of the tuples (rows) is insignificant.

So, if there's a possibility that the data may be redundant, you may need to separate it to a different table as mentioned by your friend. It will be a pain to join the table together but consider it as a tradeoff towards performance and storage capacity.

Comment: What I mean with C1-C10 is that they are a group of data not redundant data and it is not wasting of space as it is needed, I understand your point but I am looking for something practical scenario rather than theoretical one, anyway thanks for your input.